# CSS Make an absolutely positioned dropdown menu fill the remaining horizontal viewport width

Tags: html, css

Using Bootstrap 3 the drop down works fine in that the drop down is positioned directly below the menu item it is the drop down of - due to the CSS position:absolute and top:100% and left: 0.

What I would like is to be able to set the width of the dropdown to fill up the remaining horizontal space of the viewport.

You cannot just set it to width:100% because the positioning container is the main menu item whose width is just the width of the menu item. I cannot use calc(100% - currentleft) because i don't know the current left. I could do it in script but was hoping to just use a pure CSS solution.

I didn't want to use position: fixed, left:0 , width:100% as I want the left to begin where it currently is i.e. below the menu item it is a dropdown of.

You can see an example if you go to https://johnblair.azurewebsites.net/  and hover over "Sample Pages". I want the drop down to extend from its current left position to the right edge of the viewport - and accommodate any resizing of the browser.

Comment: don't think you're gona get a pure css solution to this. absolute positioning means you're bound to your container. you might be able to use vw if you know what the right is all the time?

Comment: Thanks...that's was i'm thinking too...but i've been impressed in the past with the clever ways people have used :before and :after pseudo elements to solve seemingly impossible tasks!

Comment: Actually the remaining width of the viewport was not aestetically pleasing. So what i settled on was when not in mobile mode i use "display: table-row;" for the dropdown and "display: table-cell;" for the columns - this has the nice effect that the columns only take up necessary space and columns do not collapse under each other if one column is shorter than another as seen in solutions with floated columns. Thanks.